# tmap OpenStreetMap basemap in greyscale

Tags: r

I'm using R/tmap in both view and plot mode (for slightly different purposes with the same underlying data) and trying to work out how I can overlay on top of an OpenStreetMap basemap but force that basemap to display in greyscale rather than colour. Preferably in view mode but otherwise interested in plot mode also. Main reason to do this is that when plotting polygons on top of a basemap, all colourblind-friendly quantitative palettes end in a pale yellow colour which can be difficult to pick out against the greens in OpenStreetMap. I don't mind if the base layer is less distinct in greyscale, it's just for orientation.

```
tmap_mode('view')
tm_basemap(server = "OpenStreetMap") +  # this is as far as I've got
  tm_shape(my.layer) + tm_polygons(col = 'my.continuous.variable')
```

Edit:
I also tried

```
tmap_mode('plot')
osmtiles <- tmaptools::read_osm(bb(my.layer), type="osm") 
tmap_mode("plot") tm_shape(osmtiles) + tm_rgb(saturation = 0)
```

But even with saturation = 0 the basemap still gets displayed in colour. I even tried saving to png and still the same. Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong there?

Answer (score 4):

There is a monochrome OSM tileservice at: `http://a.tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` so you can do:

```
> library(tmap)
> tiles="http://a.tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
> tmap_mode("view")
tmap mode set to interactive viewing
> tm_basemap(server =tiles)
```

and get a monochrome base map. You can also try the Stamen Toner map for an alternate monochrome base map:

```
> stamen_toner = "http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
```

And use that in `tm_basemap`. Check terms and conditions of use for these basemaps before deployment.

For putting colours on top of monochrome maps, I find that multiplicative blending works really well since it doesn't make the colours transparent but instead lets only blacks from the baselayer show through. It doesn't seem to be doable in R at the moment, but can be done in QGIS.